# Multiple Children Without Nesting?

Tags: c, process, fork

I had an assignment for a class where I had to make 3 child processes that each had their own job.  The parent was to wait for each child to finish before creating the next, and then the parent was to wait for all of them to finish before printing its own PID.  What I want to know is if this kind of multiple child processes is possible without nested if statements.  Mostly if I can control the parent outside of a giant nested if statement if I were to need more than 3 child processes.  When I tried separating them out into separate if statements, the order got all screwed up.

Basically instead of

```
if 
    child1
else
    if 
       child2
    else
       if
           child3
```

I want

```
if
    child1
if
    child2
if
    child3
parent code here instead of nested
```

Here was the original code for my assignment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

if (argc != 4) {
    printf("Error:  Need 3 integer arguments\n");
    exit(1);
}

pid_t pid, pid1, pid2;
int returnstatus, returnstatus1, returnstatus2;

pid = fork();
// Child 1: Sum
if (pid == 0) {
    printf("Child 1 PID = %d\n", getpid());

    int a, b, c;
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    b = atoi(argv[2]);
    c = atoi(argv[3]);
    printf("Sum of integers = %d\n", a+b+c);
}
else {
    // wait(NULL);  works, but best practice is to get return code
    waitpid(pid, &returnstatus, 0);

    pid1 = fork();

    // Child 2: Product
    if (pid1 == 0) {
        printf("Child 2 PID = %d\n", getpid());

        int a, b, c;
        a = atoi(argv[1]);
        b = atoi(argv[2]);
        c = atoi(argv[3]);
        printf("Product of integers = %d\n", a*b*c);
    }
    else {
        waitpid(pid1, &returnstatus1, 0);

        pid2 = fork();

        // Child 3: Sum of squares
        if (pid2 == 0) {
            printf("Child 3 PID = %d\n", getpid());

            int a, b, c;
            a = atoi(argv[1]);
            b = atoi(argv[2]);
            c = atoi(argv[3]);
            printf("Sum of squares of integers = %d\n", (a*a)+(b*b)+(c*c));
        }
        else {
            waitpid(pid2, &returnstatus2, 0);

            printf("Parent PID = %d\n", getpid());
        }
    }

}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: this has the serious problem that the returned value from `fork()` is not being checked for an error indication: I.E. <0.

Answer (score 2):

Since each child is doing its own set of tasks, you can just `exit()` and the end of each child block.

So it would look something like this:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
    perror("fork for child 1 failed");
    exit(1);
if (pid == 0) {
    // child 1 tasks
    exit(0);
}

waitpid(pid, &returnstatus, 0);

pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
    perror("fork for child 2 failed");
    exit(1);
} else if (pid == 0) {
    // child 2 tasks
    exit(0);
}

waitpid(pid, &returnstatus1, 0);

pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
    perror("fork for child 3 failed");
    exit(1);
} else if (pid == 0) {
    // child 3 tasks
    exit(0);
}

waitpid(pid, &returnstatus2, 0);

printf("Parent PID = %d\n", getpid());
```

Also note the error check on the calls to `fork`.

EDIT:

If you want to get a bit fancy and remove some redundant code, you can make use of some function pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

typedef void (*child_func_type)(char *argv[]);

void child1_tasks(char *argv[])
{
    printf("Child 1 PID = %d\n", getpid());

    int a, b, c;
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    b = atoi(argv[2]);
    c = atoi(argv[3]);
    printf("Sum of integers = %d\n", a+b+c);
}

void child2_tasks(char *argv[])
{
    printf("Child 2 PID = %d\n", getpid());

    int a, b, c;
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    b = atoi(argv[2]);
    c = atoi(argv[3]);
    printf("Product of integers = %d\n", a*b*c);
}

void child3_tasks(char *argv[])
{
    printf("Child 3 PID = %d\n", getpid());

    int a, b, c;
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    b = atoi(argv[2]);
    c = atoi(argv[3]);
    printf("Sum of squares of integers = %d\n", (a*a)+(b*b)+(c*c));
}

int run_child(char *argv[], child_func_type child_func)
{
    int returnstatus;
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        child_func(argv);
        exit(0);
    }
    waitpid(pid, &returnstatus, 0);
    return returnstatus;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc != 4) {
        printf("Error:  Need 3 integer arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int returnstatus, returnstatus1, returnstatus2;

    returnstatus = run_child(argv, child1_tasks);
    returnstatus1 = run_child(argv, child2_tasks);
    returnstatus2 = run_child(argv, child3_tasks);

    printf("Children returned %d, %d, and %d\n", 
            returnstatus, returnstatus1, returnstatus2);
    printf("Parent PID = %d\n", getpid());

    return 0;
}
```